# Can't open Talend Open Studio on ubuntu

Tags: java, talend

I am new to Talend Open studio. I am trying to open it but it is giving following warnings :

> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
>
> WARNING: Illegal reflective access by
>   org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller
>   (file:/home/user/TOS_DI-20181026_1147-V7.1.1/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.100.v20150521-1310.jar)
>   to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL)
>
> WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of
>   org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller
>
> WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further
>   illegal reflective access operations
>
> WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future
>   release

can anyone help me with this ?

Please let me know if any infomration required by my side.

Comment: Have you tried it on java 8?

Comment: No. Should I try with java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using a Java 9 or higher version. According to [their docs](https://help.talend.com/home) they only support JDK8 (and recommend [Azul Zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/))

Comment: Ok. I will try with java 8. Thank You.